# New predicates for limit comparison test

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

The sequence $\{r_k\}$ consisting of positive numbers has extended limit if $r_k \to \infty$ or $\exists L \in \mathbb R : r_k \to L$.

Limit Comparison Test :

> If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ are two series
>   with positive terms, and the sequence $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ has extended
>   limit  $\alpha$ , then we have :
>   1. If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ is convergence, and $0 \le \alpha \lt \infty$ , Then $\sum_{k=1}^ \infty a_k$ is convergence.
>   2. If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ is divergence, and $0 \lt \alpha \le \infty$, Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is divergence.

After reading the proof of this theorem, it seems that there is no need for $\{a_k/b_k\}$ to be convergence.

1. Find some predicates for the sequence $\{a_k/b_k\}$ such that the first part of theorem is true when that predicates hold.
2. Find some predicates like the first part of the question such that the second part of the theorem is true when that predicates hold.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the case (1): what happens if $a_k\le M b_k$ for some $M\ge 0$?